# Should there be used a different method for object detection when used cv2.Canny?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, canny-operator, python-mss

I'm trying to implement the usage of cv2.Canny(), but no matter which approach and method I'm using I'm not getting the object detected. So here I'm raising a question about whether there could be object detection with the `cv2.Canny`
Here's the code that I have:

```
import time
import Options.settings as set
import time
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

x = 0

offset = set.offset
create_logs = set.create_logs

#template and dimensions
template = cv2.imread("m2.png")
template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
template_canny = cv2.Canny(template_gray, 79, 100)
template_w, template_h = template_canny.shape[::-1]

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 523, "left": 1600, "width": 230, "height": 359}

    while True:
        last_time = time.time()
        
        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
        img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 100, 115)

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(
            image = img_canny,
            templ = template_canny, 
            method= cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
        )

        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        #threshold
        if max_val >= 0.6:
            x = x + 1
            print(f'{x} is used')

            img = cv2.rectangle(
                img = img,
                pt1 = max_loc,
                pt2 = (
                    max_loc[0] + template_w, # = pt2 x 
                    max_loc[1] + template_h # = pt2 y
                ),
                color = (0,255,0),
                thickness = 3 #fill the rectangle
            )
        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)



        #print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Here's the original code, but because it wasn't detecting object as accurate as supposed and wasn't working with some of the cv2 methods like "TM_CCORR_NORMED" I was recommended to try cv2.Canny.

```
import time
import Options.settings as set
import time
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

x = 0

offset = set.offset
create_logs = set.create_logs

#template and dimensions
template = cv2.imread("m1.png")
template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
template_w, template_h = template_gray.shape[::-1]

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 523, "left": 1600, "width": 230, "height": 359}

    while True:
        last_time = time.time()
        
        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(
            image = img_gray,
            templ = template_gray, 
            method= cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
        )

        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        #threshold
        if max_val >= 0.55:
            x = x + 1
            print(f'{x} is used')

            img = cv2.rectangle(
                img = img,
                pt1 = max_loc,
                pt2 = (
                    max_loc[0] + template_w, # = pt2 x 
                    max_loc[1] + template_h # = pt2 y
                ),
                color = (0,255,0),
                thickness = 3 #fill the rectangle
            )
        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)



        #print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

---

**EDIT:**

Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the m2.png https://ibb.co/Xb5tCPZ

Comment: where is image(s) which you use? Code may work with our images but it may have problem with your images. They may need some extra code - and all depends what you have on images.

Comment: Please add a sample image that helps to reproduce your problem!

Comment: @Markus, please find here a sample example from one of my favorite games^^
https://ibb.co/2NLPBbF
https://ibb.co/5KBQy67
https://ibb.co/7NsPzDy

Comment: @furas please find sample from above^^

Comment: better put it in question. More people will see it and more peole may help you.

Comment: There is too much textured background, canny will probably not work.

Comment: @Micka, even when I make the screen capture limited to the needed area?

Comment: Please add the template image `m1.png`, that you are using in your code, to your question. Otherwise it won't be possible for others to reproduce your case.

Comment: @Markus https://ibb.co/Xb5tCPZ here is the link for the image as well as I added it in the discription

Comment: Canny is an edge detector not an object detector as such.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:
Your code works fine on my machine even with screen capturing. I only had to change the `monitor` region of interest that is grabbed from the screen. Perhaps you forgot to adjust that?

```
import cv2
import mss
import numpy


# template and dimensions
template = cv2.imread("m2.png")
template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template_canny = cv2.Canny(template_gray, 79, 100)
template_w, template_h = template_canny.shape[::-1]

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 10, "left": 10, "width": 1200, "height": 800}

    while True:
        # get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
        img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 100, 115)

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(
            image=img_canny,
            templ=template_canny,
            method=cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
        )

        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        # threshold
        if max_val >= 0.6:
            img = cv2.rectangle(
                img=img,
                pt1=max_loc,
                pt2=(
                    max_loc[0] + template_w,  # = pt2 x
                    max_loc[1] + template_h  # = pt2 y
                ),
                color=(0, 255, 0),
                thickness=3  # fill the rectangle
            )
        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello, is it possible to make it work with the screen capture?

Comment: @Forseen: Also tested the screen capture and it is working fine. See update above. Please check your `monitor` region of interest.